# OBD Accessory External Power Supply

Tags: obd-ii, electronics, tesla

I recently purchased the Zubie Car Hotspot from Verizon that connects to the OBD port on a car. I have mine connected to the Tesla Model X, unfortunately I need the connection to remain always on but the Zubie shuts off after 15 minutes when the car turns off.

Based on my testing, the Zubie will remain powered when the car is charging so perhaps it shuts off based on voltage? Such as when the Tesla DC to DC converter turns on/off?

Do you know if it is possible to keep it always powered? Can I power it externally? If so, which pins?

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine its the Body Control Module (BCM - Or whatever Tesla calls it) which is keeping it powered for the 15 minutes. I'm sure there's a way to keep it powered all the time, but that seems like a weird requirement. As long as Tesla doesn't do anything differently, it should be pin 16 on [this diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b3kaj.png) for battery power ... assuming that's what the module is using for power (most do).

Comment: The 15 minutes shut off is a feature the Zubie not the Tesla. I tried to wire it externally with a 13V DC power supply on pin 4 (negative) and pin 16 (positive) but the hotspot didn't turn on. So I assume their is another pin?

Comment: Since it seems to talk to the engine computer maybe it's sending sending a message over the serial data line and looking for a response and after 15 minutes of no response powers off. Without a pin out or technical document on the Zubie it would be hard to say what it's looking for. If you power and ground the corresponding pins with the unit unplugged does it power up?

Comment: But it seems to work when the car is charging so could it be the voltage? The DC to DC ocassinaly tops off the Tesla 12V battery from the main battery pack. I tried manually wiring a 13.5V power supply to the ground (4) and possitive (16) pin but the unit didn't turn on. So I assume their must be another pin

Comment: it may be specific to the tesla I'd break out the multimeter and look for differences on non data lines key on and off.

Answer (score 1):

this may work [https://www.amazon.com/OBD-Extension-Cable-Connector-Scanner/dp/B07435H324](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07435H324)

It will allow a y cable hookup, maybe not so elegant, but it works

Comment: Welcome to the site - could you elaborate a bit on how the linked product would solve the OP's problem?